# Optimal Way for Transmission of Sound from Air to Water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics

Is there a best way to transmit sound from air to water? The route of the sound doesn't have to be air -> water directly (i.e. it can be air -> [some sort of medium] -> water).

I am trying to minimize the amount of wave being reflected off during the transmission process. However, it is found challenging to devise such a way...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a horn from a horn speaker in reverse. The horn acts as a transformer between the speaker diaphragm and the much higher impedance outside air. The sound pressure is much higher at the input end. You can observe this if you unscrew the speaker and speak into the back. You have to seal between your mouth and the hole to couple much sound into it. If you dip the back into the water, or pipe the sound out the back into the water, it will act as a transformer between the high impedance outside air and the low impedance water.